# Unable to generate mipmap for half_float texture

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am using webgl2 and loading my texture data as half floats. I can render the image correctly when using `LINEAR` MIN_FILTER. However, I want to use a mipmap filter. When I use a mipmap filter and attempt to generate mipmaps it fails. The webgl documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D indicates R16F textures are filterable and doesn't indicate it is limited to LINEAR filters. Is there a step I am missing or is this an undocumented limitation of webgl2?

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
const tex = gl.createTexture();
const unit = 1;  // Pick some texture unit
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

const numPixels = this.width * this.height;

const level = 0;

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
// gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR); //Works
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST); //Does NOT work
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

// Upload the image into the texture
const pixel = new Uint16Array(this.binaryImage);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.R16F, this.width, this.height, 0, gl.RED, gl.HALF_FLOAT, pixel);

gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D); //FAILS

const sampler2DLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
gl.uniform1i(sampler2DLoc, unit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL2's spec says WebGL2 is OpenGL ES 3.0 with the differences listed in the WebGL2 spec. Otherwise the WebGL2 spec says to read the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec for the details.

From the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec section 3.8.10.5

> ## 3.8.10.5    Manual Mipmap Generation
>
> Mipmaps can be generated manually with the command
>
> ```
> void GenerateMipmap(enumtarget);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If the level base array was not specified with an unsized internal format from table 3.3 or a sized internal format that is both color-renderable and texture-filterable according to table 3.13, an `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated

R16F is texture-filterable but it is not color-renderable

You'd need to check for and enable [the `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_color_buffer_float/) to be able to generate mips for half float formats.

```js
'use strict';

function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  const ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float');
  if (!ext){
    return alert('need EXT_color_buffer_float');
  }

  const vs = `#version 300 es
  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 120.0;
  } 
  `;

  const fs = `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D tex;

  out vec4 outColor;

  void main() {
    outColor = vec4(texture(tex, gl_PointCoord.xy).r, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  `;

  // setup GLSL program
  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // a 2x2 pixel data
  const h0 = 0x0000;
  const h1 = 0x3c00;
  const pixels = new Uint16Array([
    h0, h1,
    h1, h0,
  ]);
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,                 // level
      gl.R16F,           // internal format
      2,                 // width
      2,                 // height
      0,                 // border
      gl.RED,            // format
      gl.HALF_FLOAT,     // type
      pixels,            // data
  );
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

  gl.useProgram(program);

  const offset = 0;
  const count = 1;
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, offset, count);
  console.log('gl.getError should be 0 was:', gl.getError());
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: If I understand this correct, being "texture-filterable" allowed me to use LINEAR min filter instead of NEAREST and being "color-renderable" allows me to generate the mipmap textures. R16F is made "color-renderable" by enabling the extension "EXT_color_buffer_float"

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but `EXT_color_buffer_float` is not available everywhere, particularly on mobile. It's also important to note "texture-filterable" allows LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR and other filtering modes that require mips you just have to generate and supply the mips yourself.